# How to find the maximum number of occurrences for each sequence in a csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I have been searching for python implementation of sequential pattern mining and I could not find anything.

I have a csv file with the following data (note: First column is weight and second column is A,B,C) -- Picture is below:

[image]

```
1 A,B,C
5 D,E,F,X,Z
6 P,Q,R
1 A,B,C,F
2 D,P,Q
4 E,X,R
1 W,Y
2 A,C,P,D,B
3 R,W,Y
```

Here basically, I want to find how many times a certain combination is occurring. I would like the following:

1. Maximum number of occurrences for each sequence (such as A,B,C -- order and the place do not matter) in the CSV file.

In the above file, A,B,C sequence for example occurs 3 times. So my EXPECTED output is A,B,C,3 (I want the output to look like this). It should check all the sequences in the csv file. So it should check A, and then b, and then A,B and then C, and then A,B,C etc. Instead of giving combination of A-Z alphabet, it should check whatever in the CSV.

I used combinations to actually issue, 1, 2, 3, 4, combinations.

```
alphabet = frozenset(combination(ListofAlphabet, 3)) #three combinations. List is from A-Z
for row in fileread:
    if alphabet.issubset(row[1]):
        output += 1
print '{},{}'.format(alphabet, output)
```

But it does not give the maximum number of occurring sequence in the CSV because I am manually giving the combinations as input. So how can I maximum number of occurrences for each sequence (such as A,B,C -- order and the place do not matter) in the CSV file?

Comment: Use a `collections.Counter` object.

Comment: Is that how your file actually looks, like `1 A,B,C` with a space?  If so, then it's not a CSV file.

Comment: @user1825440: could you edit that to look like your real file, then?  Just to rule out incompabilities.

Answer (score 0):

If you combine `csv.reader` and `itertools.combinations` with `collections.Counter`, it should work: for example, something like

```
import csv
from collections import Counter
from itertools import combinations

counts = Counter()
with open("letters.csv", "rb") as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp)
    for row in reader:
        letters = row[1].split(",")
        for group in combinations(letters, 3):
            counts[frozenset(group)] += 1

print counts.most_common(1)
```

will give

```
dsm@winter:~/coding$ python letters.py 
[(frozenset(['A', 'C', 'B']), 3)]
```

(assuming I've guessed what your csv actually looks like correctly.)  You could replace `frozenset(group)` with `tuple(sorted(group))` if you want the `Counter` keys to look a little cleaner.

Comment: I want it to check for all the sequences in the csv file. your code only checks for one. But when I implement it it is just showing []

Comment: @user1825440 Your question is not clear about checking all sequences, please edit your question in order to specify that.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda Edited it. I basically want to know the sequences in csv from maximum occurred sequences to the minimum.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `csv` module to parse the CSV file:

```
import csv
import codecs

def read_data(filename, *options):
    with codecs.open(filename, 'rb', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for data in csv.reader(f, *options):
            yield data
```

The `codecs` part is so this works in Python 3. You can use this like:

```
for data in read_data('test.csv'):
    print(data)
```

Now, if the items you want to count the occurrences on is the second row, you can use:

```
items = [data[1] for data in read_data('test.csv')]
```

Then pass that to a `Counter` object:

```
import collections
c = collections.Counter(items)
print(c.most_common())
```

This will print a list of `(item, count)` pairs that you could process like:

```
for item, count in c.most_common():
    print('sequence "{0}" occurred {1} times'.format(item, count))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
def myfunc(yourWord, seq):
    c1 = Counter(yourWord)
    c2 = Counter(seq)
    return not (c2 - c1)
def runMe(filePath):
    with open(filePath,"r") as f:
        results=[]
        data = f.readlines()
        for x in data:
            count=0
            for y in data:
                if myfunc("".join(y.strip().split(",")), x.strip().split(",")):
                    count=count+1
            results.append((x.strip(),count))


        return results


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print runMe("input")
    print runMe("myinput")
```

input file:

```
A,B,C
D,E,F,X,Z
P,Q,R
A,B,C,F
D,P,Q
E,X,R
W,Y
A,C,P,D,B
R,W,Y
```

myinput file:

```
A,B
A,C,B
A
C,B
```

results:

```
[('A,B,C', 3), ('D,E,F,X,Z', 1), ('P,Q,R', 1), ('A,B,C,F', 1), ('D,P,Q', 1), ('E,X,R', 1), ('W,Y', 2), ('A,C,P,D,B', 1), ('R,W,Y', 1)]
[('A,B', 2), ('A,C,B', 1), ('A', 3), ('C,B', 2)]
```

thst multiple stripping can be avoided but you get a general idea...